# show a div message if a value is less than another value in javascript

Tags: javascript

i want to make a div shows if a value of an input less than 1000
and hide this div if the value is greater or equal 1000 in a real time in JavaScript

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: nothing i can't imagine any code that fits correctly

Comment: @ËłŘęÿNôùrËddîneTôùzânî check my answer. It's kinda real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let input = document.querySelector("#number")
let box = document.querySelector(".box")

update = () => {
let value = input.value
if(parseInt(value) < 1000){
 box.style.display = "none"
} else {
 box.style.display = "block"
}
setTimeout(update, 1000);
}

update()
```

```css
.box {
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number" />

<div class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: its work just on key press can you make it work every 1 second please

Comment: @westdabestdb good point. They asked for every second so I thought that is what they wanted. It would be more efficient to use your code and not have the function firing when not needed. I removed my comment from earlier.

Comment: @RickSibley gotcha ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

```
<input type="text" id="myinput">
<button onclick="checkValue()">Enter</button>

<div id="divmsg">
</div>

<script>
    function checkValue()
    {
        var num = parseInt($("#myinput").val());
        if (num > 1000)
        {
            $("#divmsg").hide();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#divmsg").text(num);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i have to click on the button and i want it in real time